# If $\gamma : G \rightarrow G/H$ is defined by $\gamma (g)=gH$, prove that $ker(\gamma)=H$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I get that $G/H$ is the set of left cosets of $H$ by $G$, but I'm drawing a blank after that. Any hints would be nice.

Comment: Note that $G/H$ only (naturally) forms a group when $H$ is a normal subgroup. What is the unit element of $G/H$? Which elements of $G$ get mapped to that unit element?

Comment: @MeesdeVries, doesn't $gh$ for some $h \in H$ get mapped by $\gamma$ to $G/H$?

Comment: Any element of $G$ ought to get mapped to $G/H$ by $\gamma$. That's what $\gamma: G \to G/H$ means.

Answer (score 1):

To determine the kernel of the mapping we must find all the elements that are mapped to the identity of the group.

Hopefully you can appreciate by construction of the group the identity will be the left coset of $H$ by the identity of $G$ that is $1.H=H$.

So we must determine all $g \in G$ such that $\gamma(g)=H$.

It is conjectured that $\ker(\gamma)=H$ so we in order to prove this we must show two things.

Firstly any element $h \in H$ is such that $\gamma(h)=H$ and secondly that if $g\notin H$ then $\gamma(g) \neq H$.

So firstly let $h \in H$ then $\gamma(h)=gH=\{hh':h \in H\}=\{h'':h'' \in H\}=H$.

Now if $g \notin H$. We claim that $gH$ and $H$ are distinct indeed suppose they share an element $k$ then $k=gh'$ for some $h' \in H$ thus multiplying on the right by $(h')^{-1}$ gives $k(h')^{-1}=g$ but then $g \in H$ which is a contradiction.